# Implementation of HTML "adoption agency" algorithm for handling misnested tags

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, parsing

I'm working on a TypeScript HTML parser, the source code for which can be found here: https://github.com/kshetline/html-parser, with the most relevant file being https://github.com/kshetline/html-parser/blob/master/src/dom.ts.

I'm trying to get my parser to handle "misnested tags", one of the categories of bad HTML markup that parsers try to be forgiving about, and do their best to handle. Two common examples are:

> `<p>1<b>2<i>3</b>4</i>5</p>`

...and...

> `<b>1<p>2</b>3</p>`

The second case is one that requires something called the "adoption agency" algorithm to fix, which is defined here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#adoptionAgency

A step-by-step illustration of working through the problem for the above example is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-end.html#misnested-tags:-b-p-b-p

What concerns me is the second part of Step 20 of the algorithm (in italics):

> Remove formatting element from the stack of open elements, *and insert the new element into the stack of open elements immediately below the position of furthest block in that stack.*

The illustrated example doesn't appear to follow that second part, and if I try to implement it, my parsing gets screwed up, with subsequent elements being appended to the `<b>` tag, not the `<p>` tag.

My code is working for these simple examples as is, with that sub-step left out, but I haven't tested it against tougher cases yet (I haven't even figured out yet what a good example of a tougher case would be), but I'm wondering if I'm simply not understanding something about the way the algorithm is stated, and if I'll possibly be missing something important by leaving that sub-step out.

Here's the main code involved for my implementation:

```
  private getFosterParent(): [DomNode, number] {
    // This is a simplified version of https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#foster-parent,
    // with handling for <template> elements removed.
    let fosterParent: DomNode;
    let insertionIndex = -1;

    for (let i = this.openStack.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
      if (this.openStack[i].tagLc === 'table') {
        fosterParent = this.openStack[i - 1];
        insertionIndex = fosterParent.children.indexOf(this.openStack[i]);
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!fosterParent)
      fosterParent = this.openStack.find(node => node.tagLc === 'html') || this.root;

    return [fosterParent, insertionIndex];
  }

  private invokeAdoptionAgency(tagLc: string): boolean[] {
    // The following is adapted from https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#adoptionAgency.
    let formatElem: DomNode;
    let popped = false;
    let parseError = false;

    // Steps 1 and 2 taken care of before this method is called.
    // Steps 3-5, "Outer loop"
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
      // Step 6
      formatElem = this.getFormattingElement(tagLc);

      if (!formatElem)
        break;
      // Step 7
      else if (this.openStack.indexOf(formatElem) < 0) {
        this.currentFormatting.splice(this.currentFormatting.indexOf(formatElem), 1);
        this.currentFormatElem = last(this.currentFormatting);
        parseError = true;
        break;
      }
      // Step 8
      else if (!this.isInScope(tagLc, SCOPE_ELEMENTS)) {
        parseError = true;
        break;
      }
      // Step 9
      else if (formatElem !== this.currentNode)
        parseError = true;

      // Step 10
      const furthestBlock = this.getFurthestBlock(tagLc);

      // Step 11
      if (!furthestBlock)
        break; // By leaving this loop, the details described for step 11 will be taken care of later.

      popped = true;

      // Step 12
      const commonAncestor = formatElem.parent;
      // Step 13
      let bookmark = this.currentFormatting.indexOf(formatElem);
      // Step 14
      let node = furthestBlock;
      let lastNode = furthestBlock;
      let newElem: DomNode;

      // Steps 14.1-14.2, "Inner Loop"
      for (let j = 1; ; ++j) {
        // Step 14.3
        node = node.parent;

        // Step 14.4
        if (node === formatElem)
          break;

        // Step 14.5
        const nodeIndex = this.currentFormatting.indexOf(node);

        if (j > 3 && nodeIndex >= 0)
          this.currentFormatting.splice(nodeIndex, 1);
        // Step 14.6
        else if (nodeIndex < 0) {
          const stackIndex = this.openStack.indexOf(node);

          node.closureState = ClosureState.PROGRAMMATICALLY_CLOSED;
          this.openStack.splice(stackIndex, 1);

          if (stackIndex < this.openStack.length)
            this.openStack[stackIndex].parent = this.openStack[stackIndex - 1];

          continue;
        }

        // Step 14.7
        newElem = formatElem.partialClone(true);
        newElem.closureState = ClosureState.PROGRAMMATICALLY_CLOSED;

        this.currentFormatting[nodeIndex] = newElem;
        this.openStack[this.openStack.indexOf(node)] = newElem;
        node = newElem;

        // Step 14.8
        if (lastNode === furthestBlock)
          bookmark = nodeIndex;

        // Steps 14.9-14.11
        node.addChild(lastNode.detach());
        lastNode = node;
      }

      // Step 15
      if (FOSTER_PARENT_SPECIAL_TARGETS.has(commonAncestor.tagLc)) {
        const [fosterParent, insertionIndex] = this.getFosterParent();

        if (insertionIndex < 0)
          fosterParent.addChild(lastNode);
        else {
          fosterParent.children.splice(insertionIndex, 0, lastNode);
          lastNode.parent = fosterParent;
        }

        lastNode.parent = fosterParent;
      }
      else
        commonAncestor.addChild(lastNode.detach());

      // Step 16
      newElem = formatElem.partialClone(true);
      formatElem.closureState = ClosureState.PROGRAMMATICALLY_CLOSED;
      // Step 17
      newElem.children = furthestBlock.children;
      newElem.children.forEach(child => child.parent = newElem);
      // Step 18
      furthestBlock.children = [newElem];
      newElem.parent = furthestBlock;
      newElem.closureState = ClosureState.PROGRAMMATICALLY_CLOSED;

      // Step 19
      let formatElemIndex = this.currentFormatting.indexOf(formatElem);

      if (bookmark === formatElemIndex)
        this.currentFormatting[bookmark] = newElem;
      else {
        if (bookmark < formatElemIndex)
          ++formatElemIndex;

        this.currentFormatting.splice(bookmark, 0, newElem);
        this.currentFormatting.splice(formatElemIndex, 1);
      }

      // Step 20, part 1
      formatElemIndex = this.openStack.indexOf(formatElem);
      this.openStack.splice(formatElemIndex, 1);

      // Implementing Step 20, part 2 ("...and insert the new element into the stack of open elements
      // immediately below the position of *furthest block* in that stack.") causes problems in this
      // implementation (and doesn't make a lot of sense), so it's been left out.

      // Step 21 (loop back)
    }

    return [popped, parseError];
  }
```

Comment: As I understand it, in that example, the new `<b>` element is closed and removed from the stack of open element and the list of active formatting elements when Step 11 is reached in the next loop. Your Step 11 has a comment saying that the effect of this step will be "taken care of later", but if subsequent elements are being appended to the "<b>" element then that would seem to imply that it has not been taken care of.

Comment: @Rici, thanks!. That makes a lot of sense. With the example provided, the outer loop is only executed completely once. On the second time through, it bails out at step 7. With an example that takes me through at least one more full loop, I might see the difference there, and the "taken care of later" code might end up doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Why does it bail at step 7? Isn't the new element found as the formatting element in step 6? It was added to the list of active formatting elements in step 19, no?